# waste and wastage

Tags: meaning

what is difference between *waste and wastage*:

-The report is critical of the department's *waste/wastage* of resources

-This new technology will cut energy *wastage/waste*

Comment: Idiomatically we'd [nearly always](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cut+energy+wastage%2Ccut+energy+waste&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccut%20energy%20waste%3B%2Cc0) talk about ***cutting energy waste*** rather than ***...wastage***. But both versions are perfectly valid and comprehensible, and would always effectively mean the same thing anyway.

Comment: ...some years ago, I posted [this potential distinction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63239/2637) on a related ELU question: ***Waste** and **wastage** are to some extent interchangeable, but many people think that **wastage** should not be used to refer to loss resulting from human carelessness, inefficiency, etc: **a waste** (not **a wastage**) **of time/money/effort etc**.*

Comment: It's like watts and wattage.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, just use waste. Wastage isn't super commonly used.